# Union and intersection of sets with funcions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I know this is a very simple topic but the question has confused me a bit.
I understand how unions and intersection of sets work but I'm unsure of how to write it.

The question is: 
Let A = {n : n ∈ N, n ≤ 25}, B = {5n − 2 : n ∈ N} and
C = {2n + 1 : n ∈ N}. Determine the sets:

(a)A ∩ (B ∪ C)

(b) (A ∩ C) ∩ B(complement)

Justify your answers.

Now I understand how to go about doing these questions but the 5n-2 and 2n+1 parts have puzzled me especially for B(complement). I'm also not sure what to do about justifying the answers.

Comment: complement of $B$ relative to *what*? What's the containing set that you're supposed to be working in? For $n = 0, 5n - 2 = -2 \notin \mathbb{N}$ but it is in $\mathbb{Z}$ (signed integers), the rationals, the reals, ...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Try to describe sets using words, A is a simple finite set, C almost positive odd numbers, and B something about remainders.